# Why my games doesnt appear like it runs under 60 fps?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts, framerate

Let me give you an example that might explain you my question:

When Im watching 60fps videos of people playing CoD Ghosts it really looks very smooth, but when I play it on my PC it looks like 30fps?

I have FPS counter active and it shows me that I have 60+ fps but it just doesnt look so smooth like videos of other people playing.

I know this question is a bit weird but I was always wondering and couldnt find an answer.

Comment: What sort of monitor are you playing the game on? If you're using a television, many have lower refresh rates (which is effectively your framerate limit). Then again, that would mean that the video should show up looking the same way. Hmm. At any rate, it would be great if you could post a dxdiag log and tell us what kind of monitor you have.

Comment: Do you have vsync turned on? without vsync it is possible to get higher then 60fps, but you'll notice screen tearing. Turning vsync on should lock you to 60fps, and smooth out any screen tearing.

Comment: Are you using a 60Hz monitor?

Comment: @imulsion I know I might sound stupid but Im not sure if my monitor is 60Hz.
The nvidia settings says 60Hz, is it helpful?

But anyway, I still can see 60+ fps videos, whats the difference between a video and a game?

Comment: @LucasLeblanc What exactly do I copy for you from dxdiag? I got a very long file, what should I do with it? I dont think I can post it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

I needed to go into NVIDIA control panel > Manage 3D settings, Program Settings tab, choose the game (Ghosts in my case) and change the following settings:

- **Antialiasing - Gamma correction:** Off
- **Maximum pre-rendered frames:** 1
- **Multi-display/mixed-GPU acceleration:** Single display performance mode
- **Power management mode:** Prefer maximum performance
- **Threaded optimization:** On

Works like magic :)